# RxScala based on RxJava 2.0

Tags: rx-java, reactivex, rx-scala

RxJava 2.0 is close to be finished (RC3). Is there an (experimental) RxScala implementation that is based on this version? RxJava 2.0 targets Java 8. Does this have any implications on RxScala, e.g. will Scala 2.12 be a prerequisite?

Comment: RxJava 2 still supports Java 6. I don't find any reason to force using Scala 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

So far there's no RxScala for RxJava 2.0, as far as I know.
But contributions to the [github repo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala) would certainly be welcome :)

Regarding Scala 2.12, I'm not sure, but probably yes.